# C++ Compiler tells me a type is not recognized

Tags: c++, boost

Using Visual C++ 2010 I have a code like the following:

file A.hpp:

```
...
#include "R.hpp"
...
class A; // forward declaration because the APtr_t is used inside the A class too.
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr_t;
...
class A {
...
    void some_method () {
       ...
       R::get()->mehod(); // singleton ;)
       ...
    }
...
};
```

file R.hpp:

```
...
#include "A.hpp"
...

class R {
...
APtr_t method();
...
};
```

The Visual C++ editor says it's fine (no error marked) but when compiling the project, it acts as APtr_t was not defined.
It shows errors like this:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

The thing is that this problem only is happening in the R.hpp file, I think...

Do you have any idea?
It's pretty confusing :-/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume that the line `APtr_t method():` ends with a semicolon, not a full colon?

Comment: You need to post more code- preferably the whole header.

Comment: `shared_pointer`, I take, is a typo in the question and `shared_ptr` in the actual code. At any rate, try to reduce it to the smallest piece of code that reproduces the problem. Many things could be wrong in those `.....` there that could confuse the compiler. (Also `APtr_t method():`, is probably `APtr_t method();`?)

Comment: Most likely circular dependencies and bad error diagnostics from VC++ (the error means it doesn't know what `APtr_t` is). "A.hpp" doesn't happen to include "R.hpp" directly or indirectly?

Comment: Hi!for 4 and 1 they were typos. I just corrected them ;) -- R.hpp is included directly. I didn't included more code because it's not a small code, so you can see the important thing.

Comment: Maybe show us the line that causes the error.

Comment: One of the error lines is the method definition line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My psychic debugging skills guess that `A.hpp` includes `R.hpp` and that your headers have proper include guards. In this case the include chain would look like `blah.cpp` -> `A.hpp` -> `R.hpp` -> `A.hpp (include guard prevents inclusion)`. So it never saw `A.hpp`'s contents inside `R.hpp` at all. You'll need to use one of the standard methods for removing circular dependencies.

Comment: I was thinking something about that time ago, but I don't know how to solve it.
Every file has this structure:
#ifndef FILE
#define FILE
...code...
#endif
So how to solve it?

Comment: @Danikaze: From all that is shown, "R.hpp" doesn't need to include "A.hpp" and instead it could just do with the typedef with forward-declared `A` (which could come from a separate header).

Comment: by the way, I tried replacing the "#ifndef ..." by "#pragma once" but it didn't work :(

Comment: @UncleBens right but the thing is R is using some methods of A too.

Comment: @Danikaze In that case, usually to solve circular dependencies you need to refactor. It might be as simple as moving all the references to `A` into `R.cpp`. Without actual full context about the needs and uses I can't be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a header files include loop, which means A include B, B includes A.
Normally this will introduce such issues. In your cpp files, no matter you include which first, in whatever sequence, it always reports such problems. 
The solution is don't use loop include.

I guess you don't have any cpp files. Then maybe you can introduce another hpp file, type.hpp, which purely defines the class interface but no implementation, then in A.hpp and R.hpp, you can write your member function code.

type.hpp

```
class A; // forward declaration because the APtr_t is used inside the A class too.
typedef boost::shared_ptr<A> APtr_t;
...
class A {
...
void some_method ();
...
};

class R {
...
APtr_t method();
...
};


a.hpp 
#include "type.hpp"
void A::some_method () {
   ...
   R::get()->mehod(); // singleton ;)
   ...
}


r.hpp
#include "type.hpp"
....
```